# Filling in Missing data Pandas using logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, pandas, missing-data

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and missing data:

```
Unit#      Mile        Direction
1 of 2     NaN         NaN
2 of 2     228.7mi     NaN
1 of 2     NaN         NaN
2 of 2     229.7mi     NaN
1 of 2     NaN         NaN
2 of 2     228.7mi     NaN
1 of 3     NaN         NaN
2 of 3     227.7mi     NaN
3 of 3     NaN         NaN
```

and I want to do two things,

1. Fill out the Mile column to match the '2 of x' column
2. Fill out the direction column with Up or Down depending on which way the mile column is going.

Ideal Output would be this:

```
Unit#      Mile        Direction
1 of 2     228.7mi     Up
2 of 2     228.7mi     Up
1 of 2     229.7mi     Up
2 of 2     229.7mi     Up
1 of 2     228.7mi     Down
2 of 2     228.7mi     Down
1 of 3     227.7mi     Down
2 of 3     227.7mi     Down
3 of 3     227.7mi     Down
```

My main questions are:

1. how do I get it to know which unit '1 of 2' I want to replace and what to do when there is an occasional 'of 3' set
2. since this dataframe has 500000+ lines, how do I go through the entire dataset? My original thought is a loop but that would be very inefficient and take a long time.

Comment: Are there any other unique identifiers that separates units?

Comment: @ScottBoston There is also a "DateTime" column in the format of "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.S" if that helps, but those are the only unique columns

Answer (score 3):

Using `cumcount` and `cumsum` ,create the group key

```
s = df.groupby(['Unit#']).cumcount().diff().ne(0).cumsum()
s
Out[606]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    4
7    4
8    4
dtype: int32
```

Then we do fillna with Mile

```
df.Mile=df.Mile.groupby(s).apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())

s1=pd.to_numeric(df.Mile.str[:-2]).diff().fillna(1)

df.loc[s1>0,'Direction']='Up'
df.loc[s1<0,'Direction']='Down'
df.Direction=df.Direction.ffill()

***Yield:*** 

df
Out[622]: 
  Unit#     Mile Direction
0  1of2  228.7mi        Up
1  2of2  228.7mi        Up
2  1of2  229.7mi        Up
3  2of2  229.7mi        Up
4  1of2  228.7mi      Down
5  2of2  228.7mi      Down
6  1of3  227.7mi      Down
7  2of3  227.7mi      Down
8  3of3  227.7mi      Down
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! unfortunately, when I run this, the s matrix starts as expected but ends up incrementing by one and I end up with 100000 or so different identifiers

Comment: This messes up when there are 2 '3 of 3' Units next to each other

Comment: @JoeS i did not count those special case  in my solution .